# Como usar um Cookie como Array em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, cookies

**Dúvida:** Gostaria de saber um meio de utilizar um `Cookie`, como se fosse um `Array`.

**Problema:** Não imagino como fazer isso.

**Exemplo:** Suponhamos que eu tenha um `Array` chamado `Foo` que seria o seguinte:

```js
var Foo = ["qualquer coisa, que esteja|escrito-simbolos*e_outros","qualquer coisa, que esteja|escrito-simbolos*e_outros"];
```

E gostaria de armazenar esta informação em um `Cookie` chamado `FooArray`, sendo que depois, eu poderia resgatar o valor do `Cookie` e utilizar como um `Array`.

Como poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma confiável seria transformar o array para uma String no formato JSON:

```js
var Foo = [1,2];
var FooStr  = JSON.stringify(Foo);
var OtherFoo = JSON.parse(FooStr)
```

A única desvantagem dessa abordagem em relação ao `join`/`split` é que vão ser necessários alguns caracteres a mais para a representação em formato JSON. Então, para arrays de números por exemplo, a resposta do @Carlos poderia economizar alguns bytes.

---

E para trabalhar com cookies sugiro usar o plugin [jQuery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).
Para Armazenar:

```js
var Foo = [1,2];
$.cookie('FooCookie', JSON.stringify(Foo));
```

E para recuperar:

```js
var OtherFoo = JSON.parse($.cookie('FooCookie'));
```

Comment: Exatamente o que pensei quando abri a pergunta, a maior vantagem sobre a outra resposta é que você poderá ter vírgulas dentro das strings.

Comment: Essa, realmente é uma ótima solução, sendo que eu sou fã do JSON, não sei como não pensei nisso antes! :)

Answer (score 2):

Uma boa prática é usar **JSON**.

Você pode converter seu objeto para string com:

```js
JSON.stringify(Foo);
```

Antes de gravar o cookie e depois recuperar com:

```js
Foo = JSON.parse(strCookie);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use os métodos [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) e [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var Foo = [1,2];
var cookieData = Foo.join(',');
Foo = cookieData.split(',');
```

Comment: Mas aí se tiver um valor que tenha vírgula não vai funcionar não é?

Comment: Eu deveria ter dado um exemplo melhor, vou editar minha pergunta - veja ela atualizada, já editei.

Comment: você pode gravar qualquer string no cookie. Quando você recuperar o valor, vc usa o split para converter novamente para array.

Comment: Poisé, mas veja meu exemplo novo, caso o usuário digitar uma virgula no valor ele será convertido em duas informações

Comment: Sim, então utilize um outro caracter que o seu usuário não pode digitar, exemplo:

|, β, $. 

Você pode dar split utilizando qualquer caracter.

Comment: Pode até ser, mas acredito que a solução com o JSON, seria mais adequada, simples, e elegante. Porém, +1 por funcionar.